# Material UI's CSS Baseline is decreasing my components' sizes and changing circles to ellipses

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to add dark mode feature in my React app that uses Material UI. So, I headed to the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#user-preference) and referred a few stackoverflow posts, and did the following:

```js
const MaterialTheme = ({ children, colorTheme, darkMode }) => {
    const mode = darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light';

    const theme = React.useMemo(() => {
        const {
            primaryColor,
            primaryColorHover,
            accentColor,
            accentColorHover,
        } = colorTheme;
        return createMuiTheme({
            palette: {
                type: mode,
                primary: {
                    main: primaryColor,
                    dark: primaryColorHover,
                },
                secondary: {
                    main: accentColor,
                    dark: accentColorHover,
                },
            }
        });
    }, [colorTheme, mode]);
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

However,  is changing my font sizes and shapes. 
The sizes of a lot of my custom components were decreased and circles were changed into ellipses, even though on inspecting, the border-radius was still 50%. 
However, the documentation states that CssBasline has to be added in order to apply dark mode throughout the app.

With CSS baseline (light mode):

[image: With CSS baseline]

[image]

Without CSS baseline:

[image: Without CSS baseline]

[image]

What is wrong with what I have done?

P.S: This is how I'm using MaterialTheme:

```js
<Router history={history}>
  <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
    <MaterialTheme>
      <Suspense fallback={<PageLoader />}>
        <Switch>
          // my routes
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </MaterialTheme>
  </PersistGate>
</Router>;
```

Comment: cssbaseline will change your default font size to 16px, that might be why you're experiencing issues: https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/ make sure to set your font size for your elements specifically in a css file or with styles provider

Comment: I have set the font-size explicitly in a CSS file, and yet I was experiencing the issue. Does it have anything to do with the spacing, though?

Comment: Also. more than the size, the shape is the issue.

Comment: Can you correct it manually? Or is it being overwritten?

Comment: I had css to set the border-radius to 50%, and font-size to my desired value. While playing around with the site, I tried removing the css in order to see the effect, and found that removing give me the result that I want. It's so strange though!